# React - Dependent fields in a form

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in my `react` app.

The form have several fields which are dependent on each other. For example:

[image: fields]

In this example `Network Attack Detection` will only be visible if the `Distribution Type` is set to `Always On`.

The form values are saved in the component local state.

So what I have done is:

- If the user is switching to any `Distribution Type` other than `Always On` I will hide the `Network Attack Detection`.

Now comes a scenario where the user switched to `Always On` than enabled `Network Attack Detection` and then switched back to a different `Distribution Type`(which disappears the `Network Attack Detection`). In this case the `Network Attack Detection` will pop back on and its enabled..(because its saved in the state)

So what I did now is:

- When switching the `Distribution Type` to any other of `Always On` it will update the `Network Attack Detection` state to false.

Now this works, but... I have about 20-30 fields in the form and multiple relations. So it now gotten kinda messy.

What do you guys think would be a better design here? (I thought if only I could add a )

The code is something like:

```
_isNetWorkAttacksEnabled() {
    return this.state.distributionMethodValue == eDistributionMethod.ALWAYS_ON.value;
}

_onDistributionMethodChanged(value) {
    this.setState({ distributionMethodValue: value });

    if (value != eDistributionMethod.ALWAYS_ON.value) {
        this.setState({
            networkAttackDetections: false,
        });
    }
}
```

And the rendering:

```
<Row className="select-distribution-type">
    <RowTitle>
        <strong>Distribution Type</strong>
    </RowTitle>
    <RowContent>
        <SelectBox
            values={this.state.distributionTypes}
            selectedValue={this.state.distributionTypeValue}
            _onValueChanged={this._onDistributionTypeChanged}
        />
    </RowContent>
</Row>

{this._isNetWorkAttacksEnabled() &&
<Row className="network-attacks-detection">
    <RowTitle>
        <strong>Network Attack Detection</strong>
        <div>Enables network-based threat detection (available only in: “AlwaysOn” & “LightAgent” modes).</div>
    </RowTitle>
    <RowContent>
        <LabeledCheckBox
            value={this.state.networkAttackDetections}
            text="Enable Network Attack Detection"
            onClick={this._onNetAttDetClicked}
            dataAttr={"settings-sg-cb-network-attacks-detection"} />
    </RowContent>
</Row>}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question instead of/as complement to describing your code in text.

Comment: Is there a top-level component that stores all the form state? Or is the form state distributed across all the components?

Comment: @Lambros Symeonakis Top component